# add custom HTML css with js doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I am using latest Wordpress 3.6. I'd like to add some HTML code to the page using js. I put a

```
<script>  
        $('p.content').addClass('highlight'); 
     </script>
```

in the head are, but it doesn't work.

So I want to add the class highlight to a p element with calss=content.

the reason I want to use it, is to change the_content output in wordpress. I just want the text inside of ... I would  also love to understand how I could change this with e.g. the functions.php... thanks.

Comment: What is `child_add_scripts` hooked to?

Comment: I used the code from the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_a_Script_from_a_Child_Theme_without_Dependencies

Comment: That does not answer the question is a any clear way.

Comment: than sorry - but what do yoe mean exactly? child_add_scripts means to add the script to the child theme I am using...

Comment: Your function-- `child_add_scripts`-- is defined but _is not used_, at least not in the code posted. So what calls the function? What executes the function?

Comment: hey there - sorry for the confusion. The main problem is not getting the JS Script to my theme - it appears in the html on the page like it should. I think I have a problem with the JS File. As I am trying different version to make it work, it does nothing. Even when I put the script code directly in my theme files <script></script> - it's not working...maybe you could be so kind and tell me, how the code should look like? thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the $ selector freely like this, because WordPress loads jquery in [noconflict mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). The most common workaround is to wrap all functions in your script file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  ... scripts ... }
```

If you want to put the script directly in the head of the file (not recommended) it would go like this:

```
<script>  
   jQuery('p.content').addClass('highlight'); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by cjbj, you can check your console for any errors. The shorthand $ isn't defined which means your JS will not work. Changing it to jQuery will work;

```
<script>  
    jQuery('p.content').addClass('highlight'); 
 </script>
```

Instead of

```
<script>  
    $('p.content').addClass('highlight'); 
 </script>
```

But as previously mentioned there are better places to add your JS.